# Promise not working in Node JS

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, callback, promise

I am trying to run asynchronous code using promises.The problem here is that the response gets called even before the callbacks finish their execution.

Note: I wrote a callback function inside a loop.I have to print an array after the loop gets finished.But the array is printed before the loop terminates.

```
My question is :
1) Is it correct to use a callback within a loop?
2)If not,then what are the other methods of repeating a callback function.
```

The code is as follows:

```
 router.post('/run',function(req,res){


    var code=req.body.code;
    var lang=req.body.lang;
    var input=req.body.input;
    var result=[];
    switch(lang){
        case 1:
    calculate(code,input).then(function(res){
                console.log(res);
        });
    } 
 });



 function calculate(code,input){
    var result=[]
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    for(let i=0;i<input.length;i++){

   compile_run.runPython(code, input[i], function (stdout, stderr, err) {
       if(!err){
               console.log(stdout);
               result.push(stdout);
        }
        else{
           console.log(err);

        }


    });
   }
    resolve(result);
})
}
```

As I said earlier,the statement console.log(res) in the case statement is printing '[]'.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is _compile_run.runPython_ ?

Comment: It is a module for compiling the given code in a particular language with the given input. (Both the code and the input are recieved from the front-end)

Comment: You are resolving result _before_ the compilation be finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile_run.runPython()` is an async operation and you are looping over and calling it several times. This means you need to be able to wait until *each one* finishes. Simply wrapping the whole loop in a Promise doesn't work (as you've seen) because you are resolving the promise before all the individual async operations have returned.

To make this work, you need to create a promise for *each* async operation. `Promise.all()` can help here by taking an array of promises and returning once all of them have finished.

I'm not familiar with `compile_run` so I haven't run this, but it should give you a good starting point:

```
function calculate(code,input){
    var promiseArray = input.map(inp => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            compile_run.runPython(code, inp, function (stdout, stderr, err) {
                if(!err){
                    console.log(stdout);
                    resolve(stdout);
                }
                else{
                    reject(err)
                }
            })
        })
    })
    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
}
```

`promiseArray` will be an array of promises -- one for each time through the loop. `Promise.all` will resolve once all of them are finished with an array containing all the results. You should be able to then use:

```
calculate(code,input)
.then(result => {
    // use results here
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much. That solved my problem. Thanks for the clear and complete explanation